# MySql Query browers results

Tags: mysql, sql

If you execute a query  you get line that looks like this:

658 rows fetched in 0.0110s (0.0003s)

What does the numbers in parenthesis refer to?

I assume the 0.0110s is how long it took to run the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this response (as well as 2 replies to that):
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?108,51989,210628#msg-210628
Maybe it will help